express-session does not persist session by cross site request
My client/server architecture:

Client (Frontend): Vue (Vite)
Server (Backend): Express.js

Currently i use only the http, because it's a develop enviornment.
For safe request purpose handling, i use in my backend cors & express-session:

Login & add valide user.id to session
Request to protected resource validate user by session

same origin request works (BE: localhost:3000 via Postman)
passport Login:
1bxcYuh83nhWy7k7SZ8JX7Bb2j58MaUx <----------------------------- session.id
Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }
}

passport protected resource:
1bxcYuh83nhWy7k7SZ8JX7Bb2j58MaUx <----------------------------- session.id
Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true },
  user: { id: '1q2w3e4r5t' }
}

But using different client, cross site GET-request fails (FE: localhost:5173 <=> BE: localhost:3000)
passport Login:
Nk9GDYf8nypvpTa1kQCLdTS3WsOoCCt6 <----------------------------- session.id
Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }
}

passport protected resource:
OruoNwKPX3lSg4JhtyjVg8qo_G3uJsvb <----------------------------- session.id
Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }
}

Supose, the reason is the new session.id.
The fetch method on the frontend is set the option credential: "include".
The request fails at my validation middleware, because of missing sessionUser in current session:
...
/**
 * AUTHENTICATION
 */
const isProtected:boolean = isProtectedResource(requiredResource);
const sessionUser:{[key:string]: string}|undefined = req.session?.user;

console.log('passport:')
console.log(req.session?.id)
...

// authenticate protected resources
if(isProtected && !sessionUser) {
    return res.status(401).send('Login needed! :-((');
} 
...

My express app configuration:
...
/**
 * SESSION
 * 
 * // SEE https://github.com/expressjs/session
 */
const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
  secret: 'api_1q2w3e4r5t',
  resave: false,
  //rolling: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    //secure: true, // NOTE https
    sameSite: false,
    //maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 0 * 20
  }
}))

/**
 * CORS config
 */
import cors from "cors";
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:5173",
  methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'PATCH'],
  credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

Question:

What is missing/wrong in my configuration to make my cross site request work?


Be aware that false is not a valid value for the SameSite attribute.

'none' also failed

You wrote: The fetch method on the frontend is set the option credential: "include". The option you're thinking of is credentials (plural).

The credentials option was missing on Post fetch.
Thx
